# Finding a document in an array using mongoldb driver for express

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query

I have the following document

```
   {
  "_id": ObjectId("6031dca77e510208f5d9cad5"),
  "userId": ObjectId("600b49554a19f1df7e7dee6e"),
  "resumes": [
    {
      "_id": "6031dca725f5b16515b3fde1",
      "pronouns": "They/Them",
      "name": "Jai",
      "contact": {
        "email": "jai.kirdatt@me.com",
        "phone": "2035690347"
      },
      "location": {
        "city": "Stamford",
        "state": "CT"
      },
      "resume_name": "test",
      "headline": "Full snack developer",
      "summary": "Passionate full snack developer",
      "links": {
        "dribble": "",
        "facebook": "",
        "github": "",
        "twitter": "",
        "website": ""
      },
      "experience": [],
      "talks": [],
      "licenses_and_certifications": [],
      "awards": [],
      "education": [],
      "side_projects": []
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6031de2e25f5b16515b3fde2"),
      "pronouns": "new",
      "name": "Jai",
      "contact": {
        "email": "jai.kirdatt@me.com",
        "phone": "2035690347"
      },
      "location": {
        "city": "Stamford",
        "state": "CT"
      },
      "resume_name": "new",
      "headline": "new",
      "summary": "new",
      "links": {
        "dribble": "",
        "facebook": "",
        "github": "",
        "twitter": "",
        "website": ""
      },
      "experience": [],
      "talks": [],
      "licenses_and_certifications": [],
      "awards": [],
      "education": [],
      "side_projects": []
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my code to get a resume from the array resumes

```
const client = dbClient();
const query = {
      'resumes._id': ObjectId(resumeId)
};

await client.connect();
const collection = client.db().collection(resumeCollection);
const result = await collection.findOne(query, { 'resumes.$': 1 });
```

The above still returns two resumes. Also, I cannot figure out where to places resumes.$ to only return one document.

I can get the correct document using the mongo shell with this command

```
db.resumes.find({"resumes._id" : ObjectId("6031dca725f5b16515b3fde1")}, {'resumes.$':1})
```

Now I cannot figure out how to get the correct document using the mongoldb driver for Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Collection.find](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find) method accepts an `options` object as the second argument and you have to pass the projection option in the `projection` key.

```js
db.resumes.find({ 'resumes._id': ObjectId('6031dca725f5b16515b3fde1') }, {
  projection: { 'resumes.$': 1 },
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much again. I was thinking it would not be projection because I don't want to "project" any fields. It does make me wonder why is it projection? I know SQL pretty well but it looks like SQL skill transfer is tough here.